# Undefined index on upload audio - WAMP

Tags: php, upload, wamp

I've been trying to upload a file to the server however I'm getting undefined index errors, as shown below:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploadFile in D:\test\getfile.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: uploadFile in D:\test\getfile.php on line 8
```

This is my index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    This form allows you to upload a file to the server.<br>
    <form action="getfile.php" method="post"><br>
        Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is the getfile.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Process Uploaded File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile'] ['tmp_name'], 
               "../uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']}")
    ?>
</body>
```

I've taken he code from another website. This works on their server.

This is in wamp.

Comment: *Always* check if the key actually exists using eg. `if (isset($_FILES['uploadFile'])) { }`. It should also be added that I hope you have disabled execution in `/uploads/` or anyone can simply upload a PHP shell and hack your entire server - get your code - get your DB credentials - install viruses - get user passwords etc. etc.

Comment: @h2ooooooo This is just testing. Im trying to figure out why it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok point1 rtfm http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php. Copying code is ok to get you started but you end up with the same rubbish as the last lazy person. There is a lot more to proper file upload that is in your code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes i know copying is very lazy. However i had to be sure that the code was working like it is supposed too. Thats why I copied it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form tag

```
  <form action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

`enctype`  attribute specifies the content type used to submit the form to the server (when the value of method is "post"). The default value for this attribute is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The value "multipart/form-data" should be used in combination with the INPUT element, type="file".

**in  index.php:**

```
<form action="getfile.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'><br>
    Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile">
    <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

**in getfile.php:**

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       print_r($_FILES['uploadFile']);
        move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],    "../uploads/{$_FILES['uploadFile']['name']}");
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: I've tried this im getting no more error. However I now can't find the uploads folder.

Comment: @ Krish R "../uploads/" This should be in D:\uploads\ however im not seeing anything in there. So I've added the folder myself. There are no files in it after uploading.

Comment: Make sure upload folder path is right and make sure it has neecessary permissions to upload

Comment: The `uploads` folder will be in a subfolder of your `DocumentRoot` So create the folder there i.e. `\wamp\www\project1\uploads` or `\wamp\www\uploads` if you are running out of the www folder. I dont think the `move_upload_files()` will create it for you.

Comment: you need to create dir `mkdir('path')`

Answer (score 0):

Add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form declaration.

Answer (score -2):

You set Type (or select) Filename: `<input type="file" name="uploadFile">`

**name = uploadFile**

and try to upload `$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']`...

change **['name']** to **['uploadFile']**

and add enctype='multipart/form-data

Comment: So I should change $_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name'] too $_FILES['uploadFile'] ['uploadFile']

Comment: look in your html form field you define `name=uploadFile` and in your php code you try to call `name`. Change `$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']` to `$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['uploadFile']`

Comment: This answer is wrong: `$_FILES['uploadFile'] ['name']` is the correct way of accessing the files name.